# Blur text using text-shadow css on both webkit, gecko and IE10+

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I want to make a single css rule that will blur text on modern browsers.

I have two rules:

This one works on gecko and webkit, but not IE11:

```
<span style="color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); text-shadow: 0 0 .4em rgba(0,0,0,1);">
Example text
</span>
```

This works on IE10+, but not on webkit or gecko:

```
<span style="color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .01); text-shadow: 0 0 .4em 0.1em rgba(0,0,0, 0.4);">
Example text
</span>
```

I think there is an IE11 bug/feature that stops the text-shadow showing if the color is transparent.
And IE takes an extra, necessary (for this effect to work) argument.

Here it is on JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WWTQn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just have both rules with a single css class?

css:

```
.blur{
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .01); text-shadow: 0 0 .4em 0.1em rgba(0,0,0, 0.4);
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); text-shadow: 0 0 .4em rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
```

html:

```
<span class="blur">
    Example Text
</span>
```

Like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/STm6T/

Comment: Your welcome, but remember: if the text is selected (at least on linux mint + firefox) you can see what the text is, so using this to hide text is not a good idea. Furthermore, if someone does 'Inspect element' then they can also see the source (and the blurred information). If you need to use this to hide information I recommend having a php file process it to a blurred image on the serverside.